# Pixel Masonry separation

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

In first place, sorry for my bad english and thanks for reading.
I am working with isotope and masonry plugins, making a specific grid when i need have 1 picture vertical, later 3 squares and repeat it 3 times. I did it without problem, but sometimes, resizing the screen appear a white line with a pixel, it can be horizontal or vertical and i need remove it, but i don't know how, always it appear again.

You can see the layout here: [Link to site](http://alfonsa.jidadesarrollos.com.ve/digital)

I left an image also: [Vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22mdh.png)

My less css code is :

```
.grid-style5{

.container-img-grid{
    position:relative;
    padding:0!important;
    margin: -2px !important;

    img{
        position:absolute;

    }
    &.vertical{

        img{
            top:0;
        }
        &:before{
            padding-top:70%;
            content:"";
            display:block;

        }
    }
    &.normal{
        width:100%;
        img{
                top:-25%;
        }
        &:before{
            content:""; 
            display:block;
            padding-top:50.7%;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks a lot.